# help with virtual hosts on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, installation, virtualhost

I was just following the tutorial [here](http://endofweb.co.uk/2010/10/ubuntu-vps-nginx-mysql-php-fpm-phpmyadmin-wordpress/). It says there:

This will create the virtual host file for Nginx in the sites-available directory. Simply paste the following into the file and change each instance of “example.com” to your site’s domain name:

```
server {
     listen   80;
     server_name  www.example.com;
     rewrite ^/(.*) http://example.com/$1 permanent;
     }

server {
     listen   80;
     server_name example.com;

     access_log /var/www/example.com/logs/access.log;
     error_log /var/www/example.com/logs/error.log;

     location / {
          root   /var/www/example.com/public/;
          index  index.html;
          }
}
```

The problem is that I don't have a domain name, I have an ip address... so what should I change example.com to? I tried changing it to my ip address, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Add the ip address to the listen directive before the port.  You might have to define your virtual hosts as the default server.  See: How [Nginx processes a request](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html)

Remove the first section of your server file and replace the first two lines of the second section with this using your ip address.

```
server {
listen xxx.xxx.xxx:80;
default_server;
servername _;
```

Comment: and how would I go in accessing this "site"?

Comment: With the ip address

Comment: what if I want to make it ip address/example